# How to group by using a variable in R

Tags: r

I can do a group_by by naming the column, but when I put that column name into a variable, it gives the error message Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
Column `grouping` is not found.

How can I get R to recognise use the variable to use in group_by ?

```
library(tidyverse)

iris%>%group_by(Species)

grouping<-"Species"

iris%>%group_by(grouping)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `across` with `all_of`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(grouping)))
```

Or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate

```
iris %>%
    group_by(!! rlang::sym(grouping))
```

Or with `.data`

```
iris %>%
    group_by(.data[[grouping]])
```